# Есть ли функция переводящая Maybe в Either (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

Мне требуется функция переводящая Maybe в Either, я написал свою, но есть ли такая в стандартной библиотеке

```
maybeToJust :: a -> Maybe b -> Either a b
maybeToJust _ (Just b) = Right b
maybeToJust a Nothing = Left a
```

Comment: Посмотрите [сюда](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=a%20-%3E%20Maybe%20b%20-%3E%20Either%20a%20b) И советую запомнить сайт и научиться им пользоваться :)

Answer (score 0):

Нужная функция зовется `maybeToRight`